# How can I send duplicate headers to $http in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, http

I need to pass two headers with the same key in my $http request. This is a server requirement that can't be changed.

{
    "Authorization": "Basic XXXX",
    "Authorization": "Basic YYYY"
}

You pass headers into $http as an object, so I don't know how to send duplicate keys.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my own question. The HTTP Spec requires that these two things are equal:

```
Header: Value1
Header: Value2
```

and

```
Header: Value1, Value2
```

And the second way is compatible with object literals.

See [Are Duplicate HTTP Response Headers acceptable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371328/are-duplicate-http-response-headers-acceptable)