# If PHP sends two headers, which will be effective?

Tags: php, header, cache-control

If I have two headers like:

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Cache-Control: private");
```

Which will be effective (first or last)?

Comment: Quite easy to test, isn't it?

Comment: Do you understand what `private` and `public` actually mean wrt Cache-Control headers?

Comment: it's the daily quiz.

Comment: Headers will be overriden if defined more than once. So, the second one.

Comment: About the specify case of cache-control, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4371395/3136474)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this script the second header() will be used:

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://google.de');
    header('Location: http://stackoverflow.com');
```

On your script the second header() will be used:

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Cache-Control: private");
```

If a header was defined multiple times, the last one will be used!

Comment: To elaborate on this answer, if an `exit;` were placed after the first header, then the last one will not execute.

Comment: Yes with `die()` too.

Comment: Ok,that's right! Thank you for answer my dumb question. You are awesome!