# What is the difference between "always" and "onsuccess" in Apache's Header config?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, http-headers, virtualhost

I have a website where virtual hosts are defined in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` with a header being set with the `always` option like this:

```
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
```

If I now set the same header using `.htaccess` in the web site's root folder, but without `always` then the header is returned twice in the server's response.

The setting in `.htaccess` (amongst others):

```
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
```

The server's response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 02 May 2016 16:02:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
Pragma: no-cache
X-XSS-Protection: 1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Last-Modified: Mon, 02 May 2016 15:03:42 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
Pragma: no-cache
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

The Apache docs say that without the `always` option the default value of `onsuccess` is used. But they also say that  *"... the default value of onsuccess does not limit an action to responses with a 2xx status code..."* (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_headers.html#header).

But if I don't add `always`, then error pages like 301s and 404s will not have the header set. On the other hand, if I do add `always` then the headers might be set twice if I do use the default value (i.e. `onsuccess`) in `.htaccess`. As the docs state: *"repeating this directive with both conditions makes sense in some scenarios because always is not a superset of onsuccess with respect to existing headers"*. Setting headers twice is not always valid for an HTTP response, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371395/641481. So I want to avoid it, naturally.

My question now is: When exactly should I use `onsuccess` (i.e. the default value) and when `always`? I must admit that even after reading through the Apache docs a couple of times I do not exactly understand this. Pragmatically it seems that always using `always` leads to the correct/expected behaviour.

I also do not understand why Apache writes the header twice if it is set in `always` and `onsuccess`. It seems wrong to me, but there must be a good reason for this, since I assume the Apache-devs know a lot more than I do about HTTP ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer since it does not cover the `onsuccess` attribute. It is based on experiences using apache 2.4.7 running on an Ubuntu 14 os. Hope it helps you along.

The pure `set` parameter, without attributes, to the `Header` directive overwrites any `always` attribute by forcing the argument to `Header set` to be the only one delivered. If the same directive appears in a directory, i.e. file system based .htaccess file it has precedence over the same directive noted in a virtual host definition file related to that directory. If the attribute `always` is noted additionaly, it has the effect that any, equal or different, notation of the same directive is added to the server answer instead of overwriting/replacing it.

Probably the `onsuccess` attribute, which i unfortunately do not have the time to explore now, may be handled similar as the `always` attribute.

Comment: After extensive testing, no, a ``set always`` does NOT override a ``set``.

Comment: @user5994461: You seem to misunderstood my words: The first sentence of the first paragraph says "Header 'set' overrides 'always'", but it does NOT say "'always' overrides 'set'". Your tests just proved my posting. Please revert the downvoting.

Comment: Not correct. Set doesn't override always and always doesn't override set. They work independently, if both are used, the http response will get 2 headers.

Comment: @user5994461: Jun 23 "does NOT override", Jun 26 "doesn't override always"? Have you read Q&A carefully in context? You give no details, just postulate. We should be here to search and give help an a factual base.

Comment: I tested with different combinations of settings. I linked the explanation with more details but it's already been removed by a stack overflow nazi. I am sorry, stack overflow sucks for non trivial questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

We use Adobe Experience Manager with a Dispatcher [caching] module for our Apache webserver. Adobe recently changed the code below. Essentially I believe you may need to use the "expr=" syntax to make sure the value is not already set. That should eliminate the duplicates.

Here's the reference code from Adobe:

Original Config: `Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN`

New Config: `Header merge  X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN "expr=%{resp:X-Frame-Options}!='SAMEORIGIN'"`

When I inquired, Adobe gave me the following reasons. Thanks Adobe.

Explanation:
Using "merge" instead of "append" prevents the entry's value from from being added to the header more than once.

expr=expression: The directive is applied if and only if expression evaluates to true. Details of expression syntax and evaluation are documented in the ap_expr documentation. The "expr" is looking in the response headers from the server (Publisher Application Server) to make sure that it does not include SAMEORIGIN. This ensures that SAMEORGIN is not duplicated in the response header sent back to the request client.

It's required because testing has found that when AEM included this header Apache would duplicate the SAMEORIGIN value even with the merge option. Apache is capable of proper merge when it sources the header from itself, but because the first header was set by AEM outside of the Apache instance is when it gets weird (and requires the extra expression).

It also appears that they do not use "always" with the merge+expr syntax. Perhaps to also work around an Apache weirdness.

PS... remember to change "SAMEORIGIN" for "DENY" in your case.