# Why am I seeing duplicate headers with same values in HTTP response?

Tags: http, curl, nginx, https, server

When I recently curled my company's website, some headers appear to be duplicated in both names and values. For example, this is the full response from curl:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 19 Dec 2016 15:54:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 53272
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://policygenius1424796031.zendesk.com/
ETag: W/"2515e7e2b57063c8029ea978bf98b6e7"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: analytics_id=OW53dllLeGVPZ1YzR21vOVRvU1V5WjRBeklGNHdXeERpNVNNM3ZLd2djcnpBUjlnTzRWblFIYitHM0VtdWUzei0tN284NTV3RUVrRm9nVkhpTm1NZU5qQT09--b43227e963c8680e5b2984c13483e65ae67c8b6a; path=/; expires=Wed, 18 Jan 2017 15:54:37 -0000
Set-Cookie: request_method=HEAD; path=/
Set-Cookie: _policy_genius_session=bUVTYW5KU2FzQTh2bG44WEdvcExWK2d4NzJtNUlOSnpqUWhzL2tVSkhFTUNuODFWVkhmYU9mWVUySlpDbmlkdCttbVpZOXV0NHVYY3VWbFphYlA2S0tOdmROSFVMNUJ1QWNMMFpMcm5DZGEyTkdqSTBMMnNoTi9mMmJ2L01lSlRuSGhmMk8ydXBOYVNNcXA1Z1crWXUvelpvSDlYdWFZYjYxc0p2MGdPYnhNNm1FSFpDSFpYSU9Jb3F2UFhMQTVoTm12cXQ4bEdNMkpaVy95cWVQK094RXkwVmo5ZlE0UXdoMzA3LzJiQllkMW9jZS9xZmpiMEI0ZHFVMTNQSHlBbi0tSE51NGZyeEx2Nk95c3NxNWtHbjNhUT09--d1107337bb68f2861ffc6f081012441bd7554501; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id: 4a812c77-719e-4163-a665-5059a2b1e3a6
X-Runtime: 0.133390
Vary: Origin
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

Notice `Strict-Transport-Security` and `Vary` are duplicates and have same values too. I am aware that it's ok to have duplicate header names with different values ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371328/are-duplicate-http-response-headers-acceptable)), but same values?

Second part of the question: is anyone aware of negative effects of such duplication?

Comment: As far as I know, browsers would neglect duplicate values.

Comment: Can you post your nginx config? I had run into something similar when I was adding headers in a server block and was including another file that also had the same headers.